# ImageMagick Install Error - Mac

Tags: imagemagick, macports

I'm trying to install ImageMagick on a Mac with MacPorts.  When I type the command:

```
sudo port install ImageMagick
```

I get the following error message:

```
Error: Port ImageMagick not found
```

Any ideas?

UPDATE:  This seems to be an important error:

```
`Building glib2
Error: org.macports.build for port glib2 returned: command execution failed
Error: Failed to install glib2
Please see the log file for port glib2 for details:

....

Error: Processing of port ImageMagick failed`
```

Answer (score 3):

What version MacOS?

Have you tried updating MacPorts first?

```
sudo port selfupdate
```

Then try

```
port list imagemagick
port info imagemagick
```

to make sure that the port can be found

Comment: The result of `sudo port selfupdate`:
`--->  Updating MacPorts base sources using rsync
MacPorts base version 2.3.4 installed,
MacPorts base version 2.3.4 downloaded.
--->  Updating the ports tree
--->  MacPorts base is already the latest version

The ports tree has been updated. To upgrade your installed ports, you should run
  port upgrade outdated`

Something new is happening after the update:

Comment: Also, El Capitan is the Mac OS.  The second two commands suggest that ImageMagick is found -- but it just can't be installed.

Comment: Was El Capitan an upgrade or clean install?  MacPorts apparently has to be completely re-installed following an update to El Capitan.  Also I have heard that Imagemagick is giving a lot of users problems on El Capitan.  I'm still running Yosemite so my knowledge is limited.

Comment: Upgrade.  I re-installed MacPorts following this guide: https://trac.macports.org/wiki/Migration

Comment: Can you check the version of Xcode that you are using? xcodebuild -version.  According to https://trac.macports.org/ticket/48819 glib2 fails on El Capitan using Xcode < 7